# Formatting citations

Tags: citing

I need that all citations done will be in `teal` and in `boldface`. I can do something like 
`\textbf{\textcolor{teal}{\cite{something}}}`, but what is a better way?

EDIT: For simplicity, just consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
This is \textbf{\textcolor{teal}{\cite{NAME}}}
\end{frame}

\begin{thebibliography}{5}
\bibitem[Something]{NAME} ABC \newblock XYZ
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How do you cite? What package do you use (`natbib`, `jurbib`, `biblatex`)? What style do you use? Do you use `hyperref`? You might want to add an MWE to show us what you have got so far.

Comment: Well, in that simple case the simplest solution might be `\newcommand{\tealcite}[1]{\textbf{\textcolor{teal}{\cite{#1}}}}` and `\tealcite{NAME}`. You might also be able to redefine `\cite`, but I would rather not do that, especially if you use a more sophisticated citing package.

Comment: @moewe I don't latex in details, so far I have used only `biblatex`, and have not yet used `hyperref`. I am not getting what do you mean by style, can you be a bit specific? :-)

Comment: BibTeX has a command called `\bibliographystyle` never mind that if you use `biblatex`. But `biblatex` has a `style=` option, what do you have there? Would you be OK with the solution in my commend above?

Comment: @moewe I think your command above is OK for my present purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually several ways to achieve what you want.

The simplest and probably most "portable" (and universal) solution is to define

```
\newcommand{\tealcite}[1]{\textbf{\textcolor{teal}{\cite{#1}}}}
```

If you use `biblatex`, you can use its facilities to define the new command more cleanly.

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\ctealcite}[\bfseries\color{teal}]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

If you insist on `\cite`

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\bfseries\color{teal}]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

might be for you.

Caveat: Some `biblatex` styles define their cite commands differently: this works for `authoryear` and `authortitle`.

For a numeric style, this is more apt

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\bfseries\color{teal}\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

An MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\ctealcite}[\bfseries\textcolor{teal}]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\newcommand{\tealcite}[1]{\textbf{\textcolor{teal}{\cite{#1}}}}
\begin{document}
  Test
  \textbf{\textcolor{teal}{\cite{wilde}}}
  \tealcite{wilde}
  \ctealcite{wilde} Hallo

  \printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{document}
```

[image]